# How to select specific objects to make their keyframes appear on the Dope Sheet?

Tags: interface, objects, dopesheet

I have approximately ten animated objects on my timeline, but I only need to manipulate three of those at the same time because I want to re-scale them in time. How can I select the three objects I need, and only see their keyframes in the Dope sheet without messing with the others? When I try to select three, only one of the objects appears (last one selected).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn on the Selected filter (mouse pointer icon) in the header of the dope sheet. Then the dope sheet will only display keyframes for the selected objects. 
[image: filter button]